# How can we render 2 vertical Flatlist inside a single scrollView?

Tags: react-native

I managed to build it but I'm getting a bad user experience in scrolling the two vertical flatlist inside my scroll view, I'm getting a warning also like

"VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews"

transaction and charging session are the two flatlists inside the scrollView

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You Can not use Flatlist and Scrollview with the same orientation,you can use Scrollview with Vertical and flatlist is as horizontal.

==> You need to use for same orientation as the using of the map and use the scrollview.

Answer (score 0):

try this approach by using ListHeaderComponent and ListFooterComponent

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  const list = [
    { id: '1', title: 'title 1' },
    { id: '2', title: 'title 2' },
    { id: '3', title: 'title 3' },
    { id: '4', title: 'title 4' },
    { id: '5', title: 'title 5' },
    { id: '5', title: 'title 6' },
    { id: '7', title: 'title 7' },
    { id: '8', title: 'title 8' },
  ];

  const renderHeader = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>render profile here</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>render footer here</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 60, marginVertical: 20, padding:5, backgroundColor:'red' }}>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={{margin:10, paddingBottom:50}}
        ListHeaderComponent={renderHeader}
        ListFooterComponent={renderFooter}
        data={list}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
});
```

you can see result here
https://snack.expo.dev/@sharqiyem/flatlist

Answer (score 0):

You can map your lists into scrollView
Don't  forget to give key values for performance. You have only 3-5 items in your lists so you don't have to worry about performance much.

example approach like that

```
let section1Arr = [{}]
let section2Arr = [{}]

render() {
 return (
  <ScrollView>
     <Text>
       Transaction
     </Text>
    {
     section1Arr.map((item, index) => {
      return (
       <View key={`myKeyString${index}`}>
         <Text>
           {item.title}
         </Text>
       </View>
      )
     })
    }
    //section2arr same approach 
  <ScrollView/>
)
}
```

This is the best approach if you don't want to see "yellow error that "VirtualizedLists should never be nested inside plain ScrollViews"".

BUT you can use nested virtualizedLists not a big deal but don't forget to set "scrollEnabled" to false for inner scrollable views. Actually this is *very close thing to mapping approach.*

(please give vote if this answer is correct for you)